# Condition for this expression to be $\ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

if $f>0$ is  $C^{3}$, is there an easy way to prove that
$$
\frac{f'(x)-f'(x-y)-y \ f''(x-y)}{y^2}
$$
is never equal to -1 ?

Thanks

Comment: You need additional assumptions. Take $f=0$, this is odd, smooth and the quantity above is always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x) = \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {f(x+y) - f(x)}{y} = \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {f(x) - f(x-y)}{y}\\
f''(x) = \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {f'(x) - f'(x-y)}{y}\\
\lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {f'(x) - f'(x-y) - yf''(x-y)}{y^2} = \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {\frac {f'(x) - f'(x-y)}{y} - f''(x-y)}{y} = \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {f''(x)- f''(x-y)}{y} = f'''(x)$

if $f'''(x) = 0, \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {f'(x) - f'(x-y) - yf''(x-y)}{y^2} = 0$

Comment: Doug M, thank you. I do not understand the fifth equality. Also, $f(x)=x^{5}$ is odd and is such that $f'''(0)=0$...

Comment: You are right, I got ahead of myself.  $x^3$ terms are out, but the remaining odd powers of $x$ are acceptable.